# Background image always centered

Tags: html, css

I have created a website but am having an issue forcing the background image to always be center. It looks great when the site is maximized but when I make the window resolution smaller the background gets pushed to the left and the content overflows to the right. It would be solved if I could just force the background image to just be centered all the time no matter what the window size. My CSS to center the image looks as follows

```
    body {  background: #EDEDED url(../images/bg-y.png) repeat-y scroll 50% 0;
                font-size:12px; 
                font-family:'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Tahoma, Arial, san-serif;
                color:#000000; }
```

I have a live example which can be seen at http://www.theprizeshark.com/

To get the error I am talking about minimize the window so you have to scroll to the right and you will see that the content all overflows the background image. Thanks.

Comment: A "bigger picture" might help in flavor of a reproduceable example from `<html>` to `</html>` with an image which is on public domain.

Comment: Strange, I expected a problem, but it works perfectly on Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

I think all you need to do is change the percentage `50%` to `center`

Comment: Yep. And you can use "background: #EDEDED url(../images/bg-y.png) repeat-y scroll center top;" if you want to remove any ambiguity from the digits in the property (I know I always mix up whether the X or the Y axis goes first).

Comment: `center` means `50%` according to [CSS2.1 spec on background-position](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-position)

`center (is) Equivalent to '50%' for the horizontal position if it is not otherwise given, or '50%' for the vertical position if it is.`

Comment: please check out the live version at http://www.theprizeshark.com/ to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

w3schools site is full of usefull information.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp

```
body{
    background: #EDEDED url(../images/bg-y.png) repeat-y scroll center top;
    font-size:12px; 
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Tahoma, Arial, san-serif;
    color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: FYI w3schools has nothing to do with w3.org (the W3C)

Comment: @Felipe Alsacreations well i meant in general, both w3.org and w3schools.com are full of usefull information. :) But i have edited my answer, now i think its ok. ;)

Comment: +1 w3schools tricked me into thinking there is an association for years.